# Program crash on printing wstringstream

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

The code below is inside of a DLL that I'm using to hook `CreateWindowExA()` and other functions.

The current hooked app is crashing when I use `std::wstringstream` to print the values of the variables to [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview). I confirmed that when I comment the `std::wstringstream` it doesn't crash.

What other option can I use to print their values that I don't need to specify each variable type, as you do on `wsprintf()`?

```
HWND __stdcall CreateWindowExA_Hook(
    DWORD     dwExStyle,
    LPCSTR    lpClassName,
    LPCSTR    lpWindowName,
    DWORD     dwStyle,
    int       X,
    int       Y,
    int       nWidth,
    int       nHeight,
    HWND      hWndParent,
    HMENU     hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID    lpParam
)
{
    std::wstringstream text;
    text << L"dwExStyle: " << dwExStyle << L" lpClassName: " << lpClassName << L" lpWindowName: " << lpWindowName
    << L" dwStyle: " << dwStyle << L" X: " << X << L" Y: " << Y << L" nWidth: " << nWidth << L" nHeight: " << nHeight
    << L" hWndParent: " << hWndParent << L" hMenu" << hMenu << L" hInstance: " << hInstance << L" lpParam: " << lpParam;

    OutputDebugString(L"CreateWindowExA:");
    OutputDebugString(text.str().c_str());
    OutputDebugString(L" ");

    return CreateWindowExA(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
}
```

I wonder if there's any 'better' way than doing this:

```
std::wstringstream ss;
( dwExStyle ? ss << L"dwExStyle: " << dwExStyle : ss << 0 );
( lpClassName ? ss << L" lpClassName: " << lpClassName : ss << 0 );
( lpWindowName ? ss << L" lpWindowName: " << lpWindowName : ss << 0 );
( dwStyle ? ss << L" dwStyle: " << dwStyle : ss << 0 );
....

OutputDebugString(L"CreateWindowExA:");
OutputDebugString(text.str().c_str());
OutputDebugString(L" ");
```

Comment: Is it because one of the strings is NULL?

Comment: Horrifying thought: What if the bug is 5000 lines of code away from the printing? The unknown and distant bug mortally wounds the program, but the program staggers on for a while before finally falling over and dying somewhere innocent?

Comment: Try commenting out the printed items one by one to find out which one (or more) makes it crash.

Comment: @user253751 most probably, what I could do to avoid printing a NULL string in this use case? dratenik I'm using it constantly, wouldn't help stop to check for each value, as it always will be different cases.

Comment: @user4581301 what other 'debug' options do you suggest?

Comment: (the_string == NULL ? L"(null)" : the_string)

Comment: @user253751 this would lead me to declare each var type, thing im trying to avoid.

Comment: you need debug your at the first, for determinate what crash, instead try another code

Comment: The reason to crash is when any of these variables are `NULL`, and it tries to print it with the `wstringstream`

Comment: I would suggest playing a few rounds of divide and conquer to make sure you're isolated the problem. dratenik's suggestion is a great start, though, because it is easy and picks off some obvious low-hanging fruit.

Comment: Consider adding some lines in which the string is iterated and each character printed on its own, first cast to integer and then as it is. If there is an invalid value, you will see only the integer value before it crashs on the character. If, however, you see no integer value is printed at all since the last full string is printed, you have a nullpointer or invalid pointer or the like.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem printing non-string `NULL` pointers with `wstringstream`, they are printed as-is as numeric values (ie, `0x00000000`). Only `NULL` string pointers could be a problem, and the only string pointers in this code are `lpClassName` and `lpWindowName`, so just check them for `NULL` explicitly, eg:

```cpp
std::wstringstream text;
text << ...
     << L" lpClassName: " << (lpClassName ? lpClassName : L"")
     << L" lpWindowName: " << (lpWindowName ? lpWindowName : L"")
     << ...;
```

You don't need to use `?:` for the other parameter values, as they are perfectly safe to print as-is when `0`/`NULL`.

On a side note, I would also suggest calling `OutputDebugString()` as few times as possible inside a hook, so you should include your `L"CreateWindowExA:"` prefix in your `wstringstream` text.

Try this:

```cpp
HWND __stdcall CreateWindowExA_Hook(
    DWORD     dwExStyle,
    LPCSTR    lpClassName,
    LPCSTR    lpWindowName,
    DWORD     dwStyle,
    int       X,
    int       Y,
    int       nWidth,
    int       nHeight,
    HWND      hWndParent,
    HMENU     hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID    lpParam
)
{
    std::wstringstream text;
    text << L"CreateWindowExA:"
         << L" dwExStyle: " << dwExStyle
         << L" lpClassName: " << (!lpClassName ? lpClassName : L"")
         << L" lpWindowName: " << (!lpWindowName ? lpWindowName : L"")
         << L" dwStyle: " << dwStyle
         << L" X: " << X
         << L" Y: " << Y
         << L" nWidth: " << nWidth
         << L" nHeight: " << nHeight
         << L" hWndParent: " << hWndParent
         << L" hMenu" << hMenu
         << L" hInstance: " << hInstance
         << L" lpParam: " << lpParam
         << L"\n \n";

    OutputDebugStringW(text.str().c_str());

    return CreateWindowExA(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
}
```

**UPDATE**: per Easyhook's documentation:

> Note: EasyHook implements the hook trampoline code in such a way that calling the original method directly (or indirectly) while still within the hook handler will bypass the hook handler and call the original method.

Comment: I was adding an additional `OutputDebugString(L" ");` to add a new empty line in the `DebugView` as when I print `code...\n` it doesn't create a new line. Why do you suggest creating a new function instead of editing the values of `CreateWindowExA` inside of the `_Hook` function itself, before returning it edited? (I'm asking because I'm new on the topic of `hooking`, and I `appreciate` any 'tips').

Comment: "*Why do you suggest creating a new function ...*" - I said no such thing. I think you have misread what I told you to do. "*... instead of editing the values of CreateWindowExA inside of the _Hook function itself, before returning it edited?*" - Huh? I have no idea what you are talking about now. Nothing is being "edited" here.

Comment: I mean, there's any reason to create `CreateWindowExA_Orig` instead of just editing any needed value inside of `CreateWindowExA_Hook` and return it edited as `return CreateWindowExA(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);` for example: https://codeshare.io/8pX8r4

Comment: The hook can do whatever it wants with the parameters, and pass whatever values it wants to the original unhooked function, but you seem to have completely missed the point I was making about why the `CreateWindowExA_Orig` variable is needed in the first place. Please re-read my answer again more carefully.

Comment: Remy, do you mind going into a chat with me? I re-read multiple times, I could understand the most, but I still confused about some things, about the `_orig` function

Comment: "*do you mind going into a chat with me?*" - I don't have time for that. "*I still confused about some things, about the _orig function*" - then I suggest you stop what you are doing, and go do some research on how API hooking actually works at the lower level. Read up about what IAT Hooking is, what Detouring is, what a Trampoline is, etc.

Comment: What I 'understood' after re-reading your answer multiple times, is that I need to write it something like this: https://codeshare.io/8pX8r4, supposing i was trying to avoid the hooked app to send the message `wm_destroy`, am I still wrong?

Comment: That code suffers from the same issue I pointed out in my answer. But yes, it is possible to modify a message in that manner.