# Hooking using EasyHook

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I'm hooking the function `CreateWindowExW` using the lib [EasyHook](https://github.com/EasyHook).

When it returns at the line `return CreateWindowExW(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);`,  it is:

- Returning the **original** 'intercepted' function with the parameters modified by me `X, Y, nWidth, nHeight`?

or

- It's calling the original function plus a new `CreateWindowExW` function with the same parameters?

If in the case of `2`, how do I return the `original` function call with modified values?

My doubt is if I need to define `CreateWindowExW` somewhere, and how to 'call' it with the current 'intercepted' hook function?

This is the **whole** code, i dont have `CreateWindowExW` defined anywhere else:

```cpp
HWND __stdcall CreateWindowExW_Hook(
    DWORD     dwExStyle,
    LPCWSTR   lpClassName,
    LPCWSTR   lpWindowName,
    DWORD     dwStyle,
    int       X,
    int       Y,
    int       nWidth,
    int       nHeight,
    HWND      hWndParent,
    HMENU     hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID    lpParam
)
{
    X = 50; Y = 50; nWidth = 400; nHeight = 300;
    return CreateWindowExW(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, X, Y, nWidth, nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
}



extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo);

void __stdcall NativeInjectionEntryPoint(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo)
{
    HOOK_TRACE_INFO hHook = { NULL };
    NTSTATUS result = LhInstallHook(
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("User32")), "CreateWindowExW"),
    CreateWindowExW_Hook,
    NULL,
    &hHook);

    ULONG ACLEntries[1] = { 0 };
    LhSetExclusiveACL(ACLEntries, 1, &hHook);
}
```

Comment: There's no way in C++ to return a function with parameters. Though if in doubt, look at the declared return value.

Comment: Return a function with parameters? What?

Comment: If that is not how you meant your question to be interpreted, then fix the part that's talking about returning a function.

Comment: I can only make sense of the first bullet, don't write your own CreateWindowEx() implementation.  If you have trouble making this work then consider that any security software considers this highly suspect behavior.

Comment: `CreateWindowExW` return `HWND`. not exist any *new* `CreateWindowExW` function

Comment: @RbMm, i see, how to properly create the `CreateWindowExW` function and 'call' it with the current 'intercepted' hook function?

Comment: i not undertand what you mean under *create the CreateWindowExW function*

Comment: "not exist any new CreateWindowExW function"

Comment: @Forth I already explained this to you in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69134581/65863).

Comment: But I did not understand especially `typedef HWND (WINAPI *MyFuncType)(DWORD, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID);
MyFuncType CreateWindowExA_Orig;

/* hook CreateWindowExA as needed, storing the address of
the original function in CreateWindowExA_Orig, effectively
doing the **equivalent** of this...

CreateWindowExA_Orig = CreateWindowExA;
CreateWindowExA = &CreateWindowExA_Hook;
*/`, that's why i create a new question, I'm trying to understand how to create the original function and use it with the hooked function.

Comment: @Forth "*But I did not understand especially typedef*" - then you should have asked me about anything you did not understand. "*that's why i create a new question*" - you did so without any reference to, or context related to, your previous question. "*I'm trying to understand how to create the original function and use it with the hooked function.*" - did you read EasyHook's documentation and tutorials? Apparently it already handles the issues I mentioned, so I have now removed that portion of my previous answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I read the EasyHook tutorials but they are few, and there's not much documentation, "Apparently it already handles the issues I mentioned, so I have now removed that portion of my previous answer" the issues you mentioned that drove me completely confused if I was calling it correctly. So as the way I post above, is correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CreateWindowExW_Hook` function is a redirection of a `CreateWindowExW` function that is part of `user32.dll`.

The line :

```
NTSTATUS result = LhInstallHook(
  GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("User32")), "CreateWindowExW"),
    CreateWindowExW_Hook,
    NULL,
    &hHook)
```

Sets that redirection and when `CreateWindowExW` function gets called it will land on your function `CreateWindowExW_Hook` which will modify  the parameters and it will call original `CreateWindowExW` function from `user32.dll`.

I have rewritten your function for easier understanding.

```
HWND __stdcall CreateWindowExW_Hook(
    DWORD     dwExStyle,
    LPCWSTR   lpClassName,
    LPCWSTR   lpWindowName,
    DWORD     dwStyle,
    int       X,
    int       Y,
    int       nWidth,
    int       nHeight,
    HWND      hWndParent,
    HMENU     hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID    lpParam
)
{
    int new_X = 50; 
    int new_Y = 50; 
    int new_nWidth = 400; 
    int new_nHeight = 300;

    HWND retVal = CreateWindowExW(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, new_X, new_Y, new_nWidth, new_nHeight, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, lpParam);
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: I see, I'm gonna start writing as on your answer, just for clarification, the way I was calling it was wrong `return CreateWindowExw(....)`?

Comment: It was fine. Your way of writing it is just a shorter version of the one that I wrote.

Comment: The Average Google User, when hooking an app and it crash, how do you check the reason it has crashed?

Comment: Use a debugger!? Are you trying to hook the functions in your own process or some other process?

Comment: Another process, the only `debug` im currently using is `DebugView` to print the value of some variables values to it, is this debug you mention?

Comment: Im searching about it, i'm reading tutorials to learn how to use `WinDbg`

Comment: User, any idea about this: https://github.com/EasyHook/EasyHook/issues/390?